# How to config Sinatra to put CSP on response header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe, sinatra, content-security-policy

I have an application that has a page that needs to be displayed in an iframe of another application. However, it currently has the `X-Frame-Options = sameorigin` setting, to avoid clickjacking, but also prevents the display in iframes in another application. Changing from `sameorigin` to `allow-from` does not solve my problem since Chrome and Safari do not support this setting and release to view in iframes for any domain, being that I want to release to only a specific domain to reduce the chance of clickjacking.

As I researched the problem, I found that Chrome and Safari use CSP (Content Security Policy), which has the `frame-ancestors` setting that could be used to solve my problem.

However, I am not able to make the Padrino/ Sinatra insert this setting in the response header.

That's how my `config/apps.rb` was setted:

```
Padrino.configure_apps do
  set :session_secret, '<some session secret>'
  set :protection, :except => :path_traversal
  set :protect_from_csrf, true
end
```

That's the code wroted to try solve my problem with CSP:

```
Padrino.configure_apps do
  set :session_secret, '<some session secret>'
  set :protection, {:use => [:content_security_policy], :except => [:path_traversal, :frame_options], :frame_ancestors => "self <domain that will open my page in an iframe>"}
  set :protect_from_csrf, true
end
```

Response Headers on Chrome:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.15.6
Date: Mon, 26 Nov 2018 19:52:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 18327
Connection: keep-alive
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

the problem is that CSP is not being added to the header. the `:except` is properly disabling the settings that are turned on by default, but the `:use` is not enabling those that are turned off by default. I'm following this [module](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/rack-protection/lib/rack/protection.rb) for reference. I can only think that I'm using it in the wrong way, but I don't see how it should be used instead.

[CSP rack::protection](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/rack-protection/lib/rack/protection/content_security_policy.rb) for reference.